# Clicar em botão dentro de um iframe

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando o selenium para testar uma pagina mas o botão que preciso clicar está dentro de um iframe que está dentro de um frame.

```
this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("corpo")));
WebElement iframeCorpo = this.driver.findElement(By.id("corpo"));
WebDriver frame2 = this.frame.switchTo().frame(iframeCorpo);
frame2.findElement(By.id("btnQueryLivre")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui clicar no botão. Não precisei selecionar o primeiro frame, fiz a troca direto para o frame do botão e depois cliquei.

```
WebDriver frame2 = this.driver.switchTo().frame("corpo");
this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnQueryLivre")));
frame2.findElement(By.id("btnQueryLivre")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode mapear e já fazer o acesso ao frame:

private WebDriver driver;

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/diamaral/Documentos/drivers/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.alura.com.br/");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.className("elasticMedia")));

}
```